# Driver is null when taking a screenshot

Tags: c#, selenium, screenshot, specflow, test-reporting

In my spec-flow project, I have created static Screenshot class. I have also created static methods to take screen shots. But at run time, my driver is consistently null. How can I solve this problem.

Below is the code snippet:

```
public static class Screenshot
{        
    public static void TakeScreenshots(this IWebDriver driver, string path = @"result")
    {
        var takescreenshot = (driver as ITakesScreenshot) != null;
        if (!takescreenshot)
            return;
        var filename = string.Empty + DateTime.Now.Hour + DateTime.Now.Minute + DateTime.Now.Second + DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
        filename = path + @"\" + filename + ".png";
        var ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
        var screenshot = ss.AsBase64EncodedString;
        byte[] screenshotAsByteArray = ss.AsByteArray;
        ss.SaveAsFile(filename, ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
    }
}
```

I call in my afterstep hook like so:

```
[AfterStep()]
public static void AfterStep()
{
    if (ScenarioContext.Current.TestError == null)
    {
        stepStatus = Status.Pass;
    }
    else
    {
        ScreenShot.TakeScreenshots(driver);
    }

    test.Log(stepStatus, stepLogText);
}
```

Comment: Where do you set the driver variable you pass to ScreenShot.TakeScreenshots()?

Comment: Firstly, does your ``driver`` implement the ``ITakesScreenshot`` interface? Secondly, where is the variable initialized? Thirdly, I suggest you use something like ``DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmssfff")`` to generate the filename.

Comment: Have a look at this example: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow.Plus.Examples/blob/master/SeleniumWebTest
It makes after every step a screenshot. Code for Screenshot is here: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow.Plus.Examples/blob/master/SeleniumWebTest/TestApplication.UiTests/Support/Screenshots.cs

Comment: I have made the class and methods non static. And I call the afterstep in my Screenshot class. It appears to be working. But I am having an exception Which I have never seen before. "Here it is Additional information: A generic error occurred in GDI+".@dumetrulo @Andreas Willich